# When can I compare NetLogo values as integers?

Tags: netlogo

Is there official documentation to resolve the apparent conflict between these two statements from the NetLogo 5.0.5 Programming Guide:

- "A patch's coordinates are always integers" (from the [Agents section](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agents))
- "All numbers in NetLogo are stored internally as double precision floating point numbers" (from the [Math](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#math) section on the same page.)

Here's why I ask:  if the integer patch coordinates are stored as floating point numbers that are very close to integer values then I should avoid comparisons for equality.  For example, if there are really no integers, instead of

```
if pxcor = pycor...
```

I should use the usual tolerance-checking, like

```
if abs( pxcor – pycor) < 0.1 ...
```

Is there some official word that the more complicated code is unnecessary?

The Math section also seems to imply the absence of integer literals:  "No distinction is made between 3 and 3.0".  So is the official policy to avoid comparisons for equality with constants?  For example, is there official sanction for writing code like

```
if pxcor = 3...
```

?

Are sliders defined somewhere to produce floating point values?  If so, it seems invalid to compare slider values for equality, also.  That is, if so, one should avoid writing code like

```
if pxcor = slider-value
```

even when the minimum, maximum, and increment values for the slider look like integers.

The focus on official sources in this question arises because I'm not just trying to write a working program.  Rather, I'm seeking to tell students how they should program.  I'd hate to mislead them, so thanks for any good advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetLogo isn't the only language that works this way, with all numbers stored internally as double precision floating point. The best known other such language is JavaScript.

Math in NetLogo follows [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), so what follows isn't actually specific to NetLogo, but applies to IEEE 754 generally.

There's no contradiction in the User Manual because mathematically, some floating point numbers *are* integers, *exactly*. If the fractional part is exactly zero, then mathematically, it's an integer, and IEEE 754 guarantees that arithmetic and comparison operations will behave as you would expect. If you add 2 and 2 you'll always get 4, never 3.999... or 4.00...01.  Integers in, integers out. That holds for comparison, addition, subtraction, multiplication, and divisions that divide evenly. (It may not hold for other operations, so e.g. `log 1000 10` isn't exactly 3, and `cos 90` isn't exactly 0.)

Therefore `if pxcor = 3` is completely valid, correct code. `pxcor` never has a fractional part, and `3` doesn't have one, either, so no issue of floating point imprecision can arise.

As for NetLogo sliders, if the slider's min, max, and increment are all integers, then there's nothing to worry about; the value of the slider is also always an integer.

(Note: I am the lead developer of NetLogo, and I wrote the sections of the User Manual that you are quoting.)

Comment: This great explanation presumably lies behind the [manual's](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#math) advice that "The range of integers is +/-9007199254740992 (2^53, about 9 quadrillion)."  If I understand Seth correctly, for numbers within that range, comparisons for equality are copacetic.  As the Scarecrow said, "But that's so easy! I should have thought of it"  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just to stress what Seth writes:

> Integers in, integers out. That holds for comparison, addition,
>   subtraction, multiplication, and divisions that **divide evenly** *(emphasis added)*.

Here's a classic instance of floating point imprecision:

```
observer> show (2 + 1) / 10
observer: 0.3
observer> show 2 / 10 + 1 / 10
observer: 0.30000000000000004
```

For nice links that explain why, check out http://0.30000000000000004.com/